# Setting css variables with vanilla JS on click and on load (using localStorage)

Tags: javascript, local-storage, css-variables

I'm trying to set up some simple theming with JS by changing a few css variables on :root by both a button click (theme should change immediately on click) and on page load (theme should be set based on localStorage item value).

Here is I guess my "draft" javascript which seems to work for the most part, **except** oddly enough button clicks do nothing, yet on page load the click events are run (each one in sequence!). I feel like I'm close but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

```
const root = document.documentElement.style,
      button1 = document.getElementById("defaultBtn"),
      button2 = document.getElementById("darkBtn"),
      button3 = document.getElementById("lightBtn");
function setProperties(bg_color,fg_color,link_color,name) {
  root.setProperty("--bg",bg_color);
  root.setProperty("--fg",fg_color);
  root.setProperty("--link-color",link_color);
  console.log("Theme set to " + name);
}
function loadTheme() {
  let theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
  switch (theme) {
    case "dark":
      setProperties("0%","59%","80%","dark");
      break;
    case "light":
      setProperties("100%","0%","100%","light");
      break;
    case "default":
      setProperties("90%","29%","90%","default");
      break;
    default:
      console.log("Theme has not been set.");
  }
}
function setTheme(name) {
  localStorage.setItem("theme", name);
  loadTheme();
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",loadTheme);
button1.addEventListener("click", setTheme("default"));
button2.addEventListener("click", setTheme("dark"));
button3.addEventListener("click", setTheme("light"));
```

Comment: @BugHunterUK was correct. I altered the script a little, selecting the default option won't cause a change as is. The case block is now:    setProperties("90%","29%","90%","default");
    break;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem. You are calling the function instead of passing it to the event listener which means the function runs instantly, instead of when the button is clicked.

```
button1.addEventListener("click", setTheme("default"));
```

The solution is to wrap the code in something called a [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). Try this:

```
function setTheme(name) {
  return function() {
      localStorage.setItem("theme", name);
      loadTheme(name);
  }
}
```

Here's an example:

```js
function onClick(msg) {
 return function() {
   console.log(msg)
  }
}

const button = document.getElementById('btn')
button.addEventListener('click', onClick('Hello'))
```

```html
<button id="btn">Press Me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, this will probably solve my problem once I implement it. I will test it a little later and let you know. If you see any improvements I can make to the script, let me know! Thanks again.